# How to print prop name of object filtered by prop value

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
var arr = {
  alfa: {
    name: "a",
    id: "1"
  },
  beta: {
    name: "b",
    id: "2"
  }}
```

I want to log title of second prop 'beta'

I cant to find prop values with 'find'

```
Object.values(arr).find(obj => {
  return obj.id === '2'
})
```

but how I can to extract prop name

in log I want to print like this:

```
console.log('second prop name is ', extractPropNameById(2))
```

and result must to be like:

"second prop name is beta"

`Object.keys(arr)` return only array of props `["alfa", "beta"]`
and find by id returns `undefinded`

Comment: `Object.keys(arr).find(key => arr[key].id === '2')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As by @GuyIncognito in the comments mentioned you can get the keys and then filter by the id property of the key which you would like to have.

```js
var arr = {
  alfa: {
    name: "a",
    id: "1"
  },
  beta: {
    name: "b",
    id: "2"
  }
}



console.log("second prop name is " + extractPropNameById("2", arr));

function extractPropNameById(searchID, arra) {
  let keys = Object.keys(arra);
  let result = keys.find(key => arra[key].id === searchID);

  return result;
}
```